# How to verify a iTunes Store receipt for in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

First of all, I am not talking about calling https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/, instead, what I am asking is how to verify an iTuneStore receipt from one of our users.

We have in-app purchase in our app, and we verify in-game receipts on our server before we grant the product. However, this particular user claimed that he got charged by iTunes store but did not get the purchased products, and sent us his receipt as a proof.

So I am wondering if there is anyway we can verify such a receipt. There is "receipt no" and "order number" in the iTunes Store receipt, however, with in-game receipt verification we get transaction_id, and these numbers are quite different. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am quite curious if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Apple's developer support. I doubt there is a way to verify it by yourself if you can't find a respective transaction in your own systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no manual way to do this, unless you can somehow get the receipt data from his device, in which case you can use Apple's API that you mentioned to verify his claims. If what he says is true then suggest him to claim a refund and then re-purchase. He should be able to do this [here](https://reportaproblem.apple.com).

Comment: In my case, I'm testing on my own device, so I have access to the API, my actual receipt as e-mailed by Apple, and the developer In- App Purchase content, such as the transaction identifier, the full encoded receipt and so on. The problem is that there appears to be nothing on the customer receipt (the one that Apple e-mails the purchaser) that ties back 1 to 1 to an In App Purchase transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's probably correct. What I meant by "receipt" is the binary file that you use in code, I believe it's the same thing as what you're referring to as "the full encoded receipt". Using this you might be able to fix it, however asking your customer to do a refund and purchase again is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the [Lookup Order ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/look_up_order_id) of App Store Server API could get a customer’s in-app purchases from a receipt using the order ID.

```
GET https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/lookup/{orderId}
```

You could find the corresponding `transactionId` from this API response [JWSTransactionDecodedPayload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/jwstransactiondecodedpayload)

---

For how to do the Lookup Order ID request, please refer to https://github.com/richzw/appstore#look-up-order-id

Answer (score -1):

There is source code at https://github.com/roddi/ValidateStoreReceipt/blob/master/validatereceipt.m which will validate a receipt, and let you parse it and dump out all the transactions. 
If the IAP transaction is there you would see it.

You'd have to write a special-purpose iOS app which uses that code and feed it the receipt. It seems like a lot of work.

Comment: I used this source, but it was deprecated. Now we need another solution. Looks like that source was Apple hotfix for IAP vulnerability in iOS 5.1. Now it's all fixed, and that source is not needed.

Answer (score -4):

> I am not talking about calling https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt/

Actually u have online receipt verification tool, accessible by link above.
There is no better way to verify Your receipt. Offline verification is possible, but if even it succeeded, nobody can give 100% warranty that Your receipt is valid(maybe just same signature, but still fake one).

Apple processing every purchase on its servers and if it successful, receipt saved to database. If u want to check receipt u must access to that database and request for Your receipt. So You have a tool, but don't want to use it? No reliable way then.